# AppendChild and InsertBefore

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having a little problem with hierarchy elements that are created dynamically.
Been trying to use `insertBefore` so they change place but no luck, wont get any errors but still I get the element under the other.

I have this function that creates a class called `dice-window-wrapper` and adds it to the `page-content-wrapper`.

```
var outerDiv = createElementWithClass('div', 'dice-window-wrapper'),
innerDiv = createElementWithClass('div', 'dice-menubar-wrapper');
outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
document.getElementById("page-content-wrapper").appendChild(outerDiv);
```

And I get the print `<div class="dice-window-wrapper">...</div>`
No problem here.

Then I want to add an unordered list with some `<li>` tags, using this function:

```
icon_ul = createElementWithOutClass('ul');
var icon_ul = document.getElementById("page-menu-wrapper").appendChild(icon_ul);

icon_li = createElementWithId('li','icon-dice');
icon_ul.appendChild(icon_li);
document.getElementById("ul");
```

And the print will be `<ul><li id="icon-dice"></li></ul>`

The problem as I told is that `<div class="dice-window-wrapper">...</div>` should be under the string `<ul><li id="icon-dice"></li></ul>`.

But even if I change the `icon_ul` function from `appendChild` to `insertBefore`, nothing seems to change.

Comment: How exactly does your `insertBefore` code look like? It expects two arguments: The new child and the element before the new element should be inserted: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore.

Comment: I'm very confused. Your first block adds two nested `div` into `page-content-wrapper`, your second block adds an `ul` into `page-menu-wrapper`, so it seems your two blocks works "separately", yet you ask why the first `div` doesn't have a certain relationship with the second `ul`?

Comment: @FelixKling 
This is what im trying with
document.getElementById("page-menu-wrapper").insertBefore(icon_ul, outerDiv);

Comment: @Passerby they should not be related , I just want the UL element to be over the dice-window-wrapper element.

Comment: @Dymond Your `div` is inside `page-content-wrapper`, while your `ul` is inside `page-menu-wrapper`, so you can't force `ul` "above" or "under" `div`, as their order is determined first by their parent.

Comment: @Passerby: **[That is incorrect](http://jsbin.com/oxefal/5/edit)**. You can move elements **from** anywhere, **to** anywhere, with `appendChild` or `insertBefore`.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, but then you'll have to move `ul` away from `page-menu-wrapper` to `page-content-wrapper` (or move `div` in reverse direction). If that's what OP want, why would he insert into `page-menu-wrapper` in the first place?

Comment: @Passerby: that's not relevant to the question. The question is why it ain't working. Your comment was implying you can't move elements to other parents.

Comment: @Passerby You are so right! How could i miss that ? 
the problem is not in my js file, its in the php.
Thank you!

Comment: @Cerbrus: The parent "to be" of the new element must be the same as the parent of the existing element.

Comment: @Cerbrus No, that's why I said I'm **confused** at the first comment. OP intentionally inserts two elements into different parents and then asks for why they're not in a desired order.

Comment: @FelixKling, can you be a little more specific? If you're talking about the results of a `insertBefore`, that's correct, but you can grab a element from **anywhere** in your DOM, and add it to **any** other element. (although it'll throw an error if you'd try to append a parent to it's own child: `Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3`) Heck, newly created elements don't even have a parent yet.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Yes, I meant parent "to be". And you are right, it does not matter where `b` is, but the relationship of `a` and `c` matters. And in the OP's code, `a` is `page-menu-wrapper` and `c`'s parent is `page-content-wrapper`. This won't work, they must both be the same element. `a` cannot insert the new element before `c` because `c` is not a child of `a`.

Comment: @FelixKling: So, you mean: `a.insertBefore(b,c)` <-- there, `a` must be the parent of `c`, right? :P

Comment: @Cerbrus: Yes.... ;) And that's not the case here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("page-menu-wrapper").insertBefore(icon_ul, outerDiv);
```

`insertBefore` requires 2 parameters: what to add, and before what you want to add it.

See the [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore):

```
var insertedElement = parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement);
//   ^ returns         ^add to this element:      ^ this new element, ^ before this existing element.
```

Okay, so the problem here is, assuming:

```
document.getElementById("page-menu-wrapper").insertBefore(icon_ul, outerDiv);
```

There, the parent of `outerDiv` isn't `"page-menu-wrapper"`. Either replace that line with:

```
document.getElementById("page-content-wrapper").insertBefore(icon_ul, outerDiv);
```

Or replace:

```
document.getElementById("page-content-wrapper").appendChild(outerDiv);
// With
document.getElementById("page-menu-wrapper").appendChild(outerDiv);
```

Comment: Hey, exactly what I tried but the icon_ul, outerDiv show no change in the console. and no error either.
Still get the Ul element under dice-window-wraper

Comment: Are you calling the `instertBefore` in the same scope as where you create `outerDiv`? In other words, are you certain `outerDiv` isn't `null` or `undefined`? If `instertBefore` receives a `null` or `undefined` as `referenceElement`, it acts like a `appendChild`.

Comment: (To avoid flooding OP's inbox) Caution that there's no `outerDiv` inside `#page-menu-wrapper`, so, I'm not sure if your old code works, but this seems to be also the mistake OP was facing [before he notice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643123/appendchild-and-insertbefore#comment20458937_14643123).

Comment: @Passerby: I noticed that, too, now. Edited the answer.